# Spring boot changing static path pattern not serving index.html automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot project where i have included front end code as well in resources/static/ folder. I have set the context path as `/ibo-modules` and port as `9080`. Now when i try to hit `http://localhost:9080/ibo-modules/`, spring boot will automatically load the index.html file from that. Now i want to change the url pattern for loading static files. For that, i tried two methods:

1. Setting spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/ui/**
2. Created custom webMvcConfigurer as below

```
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/ui/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

In both cases, whenever i hit `http://localhost:9080/ibo-modules/ui/` it is not loading. I am getting 404 error. I had to explicitly enter `http://localhost:9080/ibo-modules/ui/index.html` to load the static page. But in my project, this is not intended. Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As you did with the [`WebMvcConfigurer.addResourceHandlers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#addResourceHandlers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry-) method you can equally override the [`WebMvcConfigurer.addViewControllers`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#addViewControllers-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry-) method with the special `forward:` prefix like below:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/ui/") //<--Configure automated controller for /ui/
            .setViewName("forward:/ui/index.html"); //<-- forward to index.html
}
```